# Trouble converting hex to ascii in C#

Tags: c#, ascii, overflow, hex

Having issues with the code below, I get this error ...

value was either too large or to small for a character... on the line

sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16)));

```
        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length - 1; i += 2)
        {
            String hs = hexString.Substring(i, i + 2);

            sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16)));

        }
```

Any advice new to C#?

thanks :)

Comment: Since I'm not testing your code to see if there are any other problems I won't post this as an answer. If it turns out to be the only problem, any of the others answering here can steal it and incorporate it into their. Note that the second parameter to `Substring` is not the index at which to stop, but the length, so you're grabbing progressively longer strings each iteration. You should instead just pass `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your hex substring when converted to a UInt32 bit base 16 (hex), is too large (out of bounds) of the char set you're using.

Check your conversion to Uint32 and *make sure* that it can be converted to char indeed, meaning it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

As @Lasse points out, `Substring` takes a start index and a *length*, but it looks like you're trying to pass it a start index and a *stop index*, since you're passing `i + 2` to every call. This means that the first iteration will create a two-character substring, the second will be a three-character substring, and so on. Just pass `2` to it:

```
String hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
```

That should correct the actual problem.

While this isn't breaking anything, you should be aware that what you're doing is *not* converting to ASCII. ASCII is a particular character encoding, and `Convert.ToChar` converts a numeric to its corresponding *Unicode* (UTF-16, particularly) character. As long as your values range only from `0` to `127` (`00` to `7F` in hex), then you're fine for all practical purposes, since the Unicode formats share characters with the standard ASCII character set. If, however, your characters use one of the extensions onto ASCII (Latin-1, for example, which is common on Windows), then these characters will *not* match.

If your data is in ASCII format and you need to support values greater than 127, you can convert your hex string to a `byte[]`, then pass that to the `ASCIIEncoding` class to parse that data using the ASCII format:

```
byte[] data = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];

for(int i = 0; i < hexString.Length - 1; i += 2)
{
    data[i / 2] = byte.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2));
}

string output = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

Comment: Give an example of an ASCII character, ANY character, for which the original code does not work.  You can't, because characters 0 to 127 of Unicode are the entire ASCII character set, in the same order.

Comment: Even in UTF-8, 0 to 127 is represented as 1 byte just as it is in ASCII.

Comment: Yes, characters in the ASCII range are the same; however, the OP's code is capable of processing non-ASCII values, and what he's referring to as "ASCII" may be one of the extended ASCII character sets, such as Latin-1, which is *not* the same with any of the Unicode formats. The code which actually deals with the characters as ASCII and not the convenience of UTF-ASCII parity is no more complex, so why not use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
string assumedASCII = string.Format(@"\x{0:x4}", (int)hexString);
```